# Who deserves the acceptance of the answer in questions?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have several questions with really good answers.  However I'm not sure what to do right now....who deserves the best answer in questions? Most upvoted answer or my favourite answer? Good night!

Comment: [Accepting](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) is a way to show that an answer was really helpful to you. Just wait a few days after asking a question and then choose the one that helped you the most. Or don't choose any at all. You don't have to accept an answer if you feel there is something missing. In fact there was a recent discussion about [accepting answers](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/should-moderators-mark-a-high-voted-answer-as-the-accepted-answer-after-a-while) on Meta that might help you. It's your choice and yours alone.

Comment: It's your choice.  People commonly tag the highest voted one, but you don't have to.  Just choose the answer that you (personally) feel best suits your question.  If none do, then you can either set a bounty, or edit your question to make your needs more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The issue with multiple answers](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/the-issue-with-multiple-answers)

Answer (score 4):

The acceptance mark is an indicator of what helped you, the person who asked the question, the most.  On some sites you can test answers (compile the code, etc) and that can help you choose, but that doesn't work so well on Worldbuilding.  Most users, I think, are guided by the community voting, but you aren't required to go by voting.  If the community really hates an answer you should ask yourself why before following its advice and marking it correct, but you're allowed to disagree with the community.

You don't have to accept an answer.  The absence of an acceptance is ambiguous; it might mean you need more help or it might mean you got several good answers and can't choose.  Sometimes we just have to tolerate ambiguity. :-)

It's also ok to to wait.  Newer users sometimes accept an answer within a few hours of asking; I find it's better to wait a few days (or sometimes a lot longer).

Comment: I'll note that sometimes I get an answer that isn't necessarily "the best" but which tips my thinking such that I enter a cascade of new possibilities (be it design, programming, or worldbuilding).  That'd be the one I'd mark as "accepted" even if another answer is more heavily up-voted.  Generally for things that have a "right" answer ("solve this bug") it ends up being the same one that gets all the votes, but for more subjective things I'll upvote anything that helped and the one that made me go "oh! oh! and if I do this...!" gets the extra praise, as it were.